# How can I generate unique class name for div inside a for loop in velocity template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, velocity

I have a for loop inside my velocity template to display element on web page. I am wrapping them inside div but I end up having same div name for all the elements. How can I make sure that all the div is having unique class name for all the elements.

```
    #foreach($i in [0..$size])
        <div class= "styles">
             <span class="actor">$discoverActorConfs.get($i).actor</span>
             <span class="remove aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-    remove" title="Remove project" data key="$discoverActorConfs.get($i).actor" onclick="transit_time_remove_proj('$discoverActorConfs.get($i).actor')">
             </span>

        </div>
```

So that I can have unique class name while using it inside script tag.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {


            $('div.new-div, div.styles').connections();

            var connections = $('connection, inner');
            setInterval(function() { connections.connections('update') }, 100);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: It is ok to have items with the same class names. If you want to be able to separate these items, you could just use the `$i` variable and make a prefix like `item-$i`. Alternatively you could make this unique identifier an id attribute, which may be numeric since html5.

Comment: why have unique class names? that's sort of clashing with the purpose of having classes. you should rather have unique IDs for each div.

Comment: @NicoO  I have to apply some property using javascript on those elements so I need to have separate class names for them.

Comment: I did not tell you that you should not do this. But it would be wise to use the `id` attribute for this purpose. Anyways you can use the view variable `$i` to get unique information like an item id. Good luck.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary: For your convenience if I have id , how do I generate unique Id for those elements.

Comment: `#foreach($i in [0..$size])
        <div class= styles id="div-$i">` could do! then you can have the desired behaviour of divs using these unique IDs through javascript/css

Comment: And one more thing, in your problem, `<div class= styles>` should be `<div class= "styles">` So my solution for IDs would be, `#foreach($i in [0..$size]) <div class= "styles" id="div-$i">`

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary: I just updated my question so that it will give you a fair idea of why I am using the same. Also $i goes out of scope as soon as I try to access it inside the script tag.

Comment: saw it, you do not need to access `$i` with the solution that I've provided, you would get IDs like, `div-0, div-1, div-2` or class names as `styles-0, styles-1`etc. All you got to do is filter out these div IDs or class names using a suitable selector and carry on with the logic. Also, your `$(document).ready(function() {` would execute when the DOM is ready, i.e., your DOM would not contain `$i` it would have been moulded into the different IDs or class names as I've mentioned.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary: How can I filter those class name as those are all dynamic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83119/discussion-between-user2900150-and-sudhansu-choudhary).

Comment: @user2900150 from the API I see this,

`$('div.child').connections({ from: '#parent' }).length;`

which makes me think, you don't need dynamic generated classes, have a single class as `class="styles"` and do this,

`$('div.styles').connections({ from: 'div.new-div' }).length;`

or have unique classes and reverse the order of connections as,
`$( "[class^=div-]" ).each( function( index, element){ 
var elm = $(element); 
$('elm, div.new-div').connections(); 
});`

Comment: Thanks @SudhansuChoudhary: I actually not needed to generate multiple classes. Your solution is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having unique classes is sort of clashing with the purpose of having classes. you should rather have unique IDs for each div. 
However if you want to generate unique classes,

```
#foreach($i in [0..$size])
        <div class= "styles-$i">
             <span class="actor">$discoverActorConfs.get($i).actor</span>
             <span class="remove aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-    remove" title="Remove project" data key="$discoverActorConfs.get($i).actor" onclick="transit_time_remove_proj('$discoverActorConfs.get($i).actor')">
             </span>
      </div>
```

If you pick to go with unique IDs, you could do,

```
#foreach($i in [0..$size])
            <div class= "styles" id="div-$i">
                 <span class="actor">$discoverActorConfs.get($i).actor</span>
                 <span class="remove aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-    remove" title="Remove project" data key="$discoverActorConfs.get($i).actor" onclick="transit_time_remove_proj('$discoverActorConfs.get($i).actor')">
                 </span>
    </div>
```

All you got to do is append `-$i` which makes sure that ID/class names are unique